# Emacs c-mode fill-paragraph with Doxygen Comments

Tags: emacs, doxygen, c-mode

I have a question that is very similar to [Getting Emacs fill-paragraph to play nice with javadoc-like comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788/getting-emacs-fill-paragraph-to-play-nice-with-javadoc-like-comments), but I wasn't sure if I would get many answers in a year old thread.

Anyhow, I have C code that has some Doxygen comments that look like the following:

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @param[in,out] var1 : <Long description that needs to be wrapped.>
 * @param[in,out] var2 : <Description2>
 */
```

Now, when I use M-q in emacs, I want the following:

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @param[in,out] var1 : <Long description that needs
 *                       to be wrapped.>
 * @param[in,out] var2 : <Description2>
 */
```

But, current I get the following:

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @param[in,out] var1 : <Long description that needs
 * to be wrapped.>  @param[in,out] var2 : <Description2>
 */
```

Doing some research, it looked like I needed to set the paragraph-start variable in emacs to recognize the "@param."  I found another question on stack overflow ([Getting Emacs fill-paragraph to play nice with javadoc-like comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788/getting-emacs-fill-paragraph-to-play-nice-with-javadoc-like-comments)), that had a sample regular expression.  I modified it a bit to fit my requirements, and I tested it inside of Search->Regex Forward, and it highlighted each @param sentence correctly.

I used the following regular expression `"^\s-*\*\s-*\(@param\).*$"`

So, I tried setting the given regular expression as my paragraph-start (with the added \'s required for the elisp syntax) in my .emacs file.  When I opened a new emacs window and tried out the M-q, the same error was occurring.  Is there something I am missing?  Is M-q used differently in c-mode?  Should I check my .emacs file for something that may be causing an error here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question, "Is M-q used differently in c-mode?", `describe-key` (bound to C-h k) is your friend. While visiting the buffer with the C file, type C-h k M-q and it will tell you exactly what function M-q is bound to.  In this case, it is `c-fill-paragraph`, which ultimately uses `paragraph-start`, the variable you found in that other question.

I found that this regular expression used as `paragraph-start` will wrap lines and treat each @param as a new paragraph:

`"^[  ]*\\(//+\\|\\**\\)[  ]*\\([  ]*$\\|@param\\)\\|^\f"`

However, it will not indent the wrappedlines as you want.  It will make your example look like this:

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @param[in,out] var1 : <Long description that needs
 * to be wrapped.>
 * @param[in,out] var2 : <Description2>
 */
```

I hope it still works better for you. Let me know if you figure out the indenting.

Comment: I tried adding the regular expression that you mentioned in my .emacs file, but I am still having the same issue with the second @param not being recognized as a new paragraph.

I realize that fixing the paragraph-state will not solve my indentation issue, but this would be a very helpful place to start =).  After writing the initial post, I realized that I should have noted that it was really a two part question:

1) Recognize the @param as a new paragraph.
2) Properly indent the descriptions.

Comment: When you are in the buffer with this file, what does `C-h v paragraph-start` return?  If not the above regexp, then you may have set it globally and it may be getting overwritten by c-mode.  If that is the case, then you can set this in a c-mode hook.